# Is the supply and demand elasticity equal at the equilibrium?

Tags: supply-and-demand, elasticity, general-equilibrium

I am working through homeowrk problems and we were asked to calculate the supply and demand at the equilibruim using either the point or arc method. I chose to use the point method and will provide a picture of the graph within  this post. THe demand equation is 100-2p=Q and supply is -20+2p=Q.
Here are my calculations [note the equilibrium occurs at (40,30)]

Demand elasticity: point method
= Slope* (P/Q)

- = -2(30/40)
- = -2(3/4)
  Elasticity = -1.5 = 1.5
  Therefore the demand elasticity is 1.5.

Supply elasticity: point method
= 2(30/40)
=2(3/4)
Elasticity = 1.5
Therefore the supply elasticity is 1.5

[image: Graph with equilibrium]

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that at the equilibrium point the elasticity of demand is equal to the elasticity of supply.

**This is a coincidence in your particular example,** depending on the fact that the slope of the demand function and the slope of the supply function are equal in absolute value: they are $-2$ and $2$.

Consider the formula of the point elasticity you wrote:

$\epsilon=|Slope|\times \frac {P}{Q}$.

The value of the elasticity **depends on both $|Slope|$, the absolute value of the slope of the functions,  and on the ratio $\frac {P}{Q}$.**

$\frac {P}{Q}$ at the equilibrium point is of course equal for demand and supply, because the equilibrium point is a point that belongs to both functions.

But **nothing ensures that the slope of demand and supply functions are equal** (in absolute value).

Consider the example in the graph below, where it is clear that the slopes of demand and supply, $-b$ and $a$, are different in absolute value, and $a>b$:

[image]

Therefore, the point elasticity of supply $\epsilon_S$ is

$\epsilon_S= a\times \frac {30}{40}$

and the point elasticity of demand is

$\epsilon_D= b\times \frac {30}{40}$.

They are evidently different and $\epsilon_S>\epsilon_D$.

Answer (score 1):

supply & demand elasticities are independent of each other and don't depend on the equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

No, the supply and demand elasticity are not always equal at the equilibrium.

Here is an example of a market where the elasticity of demand and supply are not equal at the equilibrium. Suppose the demand curve for a good is given by the equation Qd = 20 - 2P and the supply curve for the good is given by the equation Qs = 2P. The equilibrium price for the good is P = 5 and the equilibrium quantity is Q = 10. The elasticity of demand at the equilibrium is -1 and the elasticity of supply at the equilibrium is 1. Therefore, the elasticity of demand is not equal to the elasticity of supply at the equilibrium.